# Running Pig Script on EMR

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, emr, amazon-emr

So I am using the following file as input:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/tutorial/data/excite-small.log

and the code I have right now is

```
-- FileName: excite-small.log
log  = LOAD 'excite-small.log' AS (user, timestamp, query);
grpd = GROUP log BY user;
cntd = FOREACH grpd GENERATE group, COUNT(log);
STORE cntd INTO 'output'
```

I run this job on EMR using the steps mentioned at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-pig-launch.html

** I have set the following parameters **

```
1. For Script Location: s3://mybucket/test.pig
2. For Input Location:  s3://mybucket/excite-small.log
3. For Output Location: s3://mybucket/
4. Arguments: Blank
```

When I run this job, I get an error as `Input path does not exist`. I think this is got to do with `REGISTER` but I am not really sure. Could anyone suggest want am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PIG script, refer to the input file in full, eg:

```
log  = LOAD 's3://mybucket/excite-small.log' AS (user, timestamp, query);
```

Or, use the passed-in INPUT path:

```
log = LOAD '$INPUT' AS (user, timestamp, query);
```

Found a good explanation here:

- [Analyzing Logs with Pig and Elastic MapReduce](http://sysadvent.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/day-10-analyzing-logs-with-pig-and.html)